# Angular 4 Recursive bootstrap accordion

Tags: angular, accordion, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to write a recursive component that creates multiple levels of accordions dynamically. However, every time I try add the *data-parent* id as a variable, it complains. Here is a simple non-recursive example of what I'd like to achieve (it doesnt like **data-parent="#{{count}}"**). However, if I assign data-parent to a static variable like **data-parent="#1"** like in Group 2 and 3, then it works perfectly, but i need it to be dynamic for my recursive function.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="panel-group" id="{{count}}">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#{{count}}" href="#collapse1">{{count}}</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1"class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">Some body text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#1" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Some body text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#1" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Some body data</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using ng-bootstrap at all? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples

Comment: also facing same issue